# Virtual function being implemented without any initialization in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

Consider the following code :

```
class parent_print():
    
    def print_word(self):
        self.print_hello()
        
class child_print(parent_print):
    
    def print_hello(self):
        print('Hello')
        
        
basic_print = child_print()
basic_print.print_word()
```

Here I am assuming that *print_hello()* is a virtual function in the parent class. And all the children of parent (parent_print) will have a method implemented named *print_hello*. So that all children can call a single function *print_word* and appropriate binding to the print_hello function is done based on the child's method implementation.

But in languages like C++ we need to specifically say that a function is virtual in the parent class with the *virtual* keyword and also use the function destructor symbol ~.

But how is this possible in python with no mention in python parent class to the function *print_hello()* being a virtual function.

I am assuming that the concept that python uses is that of virtual functions , if I am wrong please correct me and explain the concept.

Comment: Search for abstract method

Comment: *All* methods in Python behave like virtual methods in C++. It's not a distinction that needs to be stated. `self` is just an object passed to `parent_print.print_word`, and that object's method resolution order is what determines which method `self.print_hello` refers to, not its use in a `parent_print` method.

Comment: Many things that the compiler does in a language like C or C++ (figuring out the addresses of methods that are called, for example) is done at runtime in Python and other dynamic languages. Python doesn't know whether a method exists (and is callable) until you try to call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than thinking of this as being a matter of "virtual functions", it might be more useful to think of this as an example of "duck typing".  In this expression:

```
self.print_hello()
```

we simply access the `print_hello` attribute of `self` (whatever it might be), and then call it.  If it doesn't have such an attribute, an `AttributeError` is raised at runtime.  If the attribute isn't callable, a `TypeError` is raised.  That's all there is to it.  No assumptions are made about the type of `self` -- we simply ask it to "quack like a duck" and see if it can.

The danger of duck typing is that it's very easy to accidentally ask something to quack that does not in fact know how to quack -- if you instantiate a `parent_print` and call `print_word` on it, it will fail:

```
abstract_print = parent_print()
abstract_print.print_word()
# raises AttributeError: 'parent_print' object has no attribute 'print_hello'
```

Python does have support for static type declarations and the concept of abstract classes, which can help you avoid mistakes.  For example, if we run a static type checker (`mypy`) on your code as-is, we'll get an error:

```
test.py:4: error: "parent_print" has no attribute "print_hello"
```

which is exactly correct -- from a static typing perspective, it's not valid to call `print_hello` since we haven't established that all `parent_print` instances have such an attribute.

To fix this, we can declare `print_hello` as an abstract method (I'll also clean up the names to match standard Python conventions, in the interest of building good habits):

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class ParentPrint(ABC):
    
    @abstractmethod
    def print_hello(self) -> None: ...

    def print_word(self) -> None:
        self.print_hello()
        
class ChildPrint(ParentPrint):
    
    def print_hello(self) -> None:
        print('Hello')
        
        
basic_print = ChildPrint()
basic_print.print_word()
```

Now the code typechecks with no issues.

The `@abstractmethod` decorator also indicates that the class is abstract ("pure virtual") and can't be instantiated.  If we attempt to create a `ParentPrint`, or *any* subclass of it that doesn't provide an implementation of the abstract method, we get an error, *both* statically from `mypy` and at runtime in the form of a `TypeError` that is raised as soon as you try to instantiate the object (before you even try to call the abstract method):

```
abstract_print = ParentPrint()
# raises error: Cannot instantiate abstract class "ParentPrint" with abstract attribute "print_hello"
```

Comment: Thanks for the easy explaination